# How do I label plot tick marks using ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to change the tick labels in a `ggvis` plot. My data points are `x = c(1,2,3)` and `y = c(1,2,3)`. However, the following code results in tick labels which make no sense at all!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3) ) %>%
  ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_axis("x", properties=axis_props(
    labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10, text = c("one","two","three"  )      )
   )
   )
```

gives:

[image]

I imagine that I have to format the ticks as well, or at least tell `ggvis` which ticks to label?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the `text` property in a *wrong* manner.

`ggvis` itself only performs data binding and processing in R. It then "translates" the `ggvis` object into the *visualization grammar* defined by `vega.js`, which builds on top of `d3.js` to perform the actual rendering.

So, `add_axis` is simply a thin wrapper in `ggvis` for defining Axes properties in `vega.js`. You can find more about this using [this document](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Axes).

You can pretty much see that the arguments you pass to `add_axis()` function have a one-to-one mapping to the JSON specifications you would specify in `vega.js`. 
Therefore, `properties=axis_props(...)` in `ggvis` maps to the **properties** of [**Axis properties**](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Axes#axis-properties) (I know it may sound confusing. But click above link and you would see the hierarchy there).

The **properties** parameter will define, I'm quoting the document here,

> Optional mark property definitions for custom **axis styling**. The input object can include sub-objects for ticks (both major and minor), majorTicks, minorTicks, labels and axis (for the axis line).

Hence, the **properties** parameter is only supposed to change the **styling**, including the styling of `labels`, `ticks`, and the `axis` lines.

Your code :

```
properties=axis_props(labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10, 
                      text = c("one","two","three"))
```

can be abstracted as

```
properties=axis_props(labels=list(...))
```

which, based on our above discussion, is manipulating the **styling** of the axis `labels`. 
Each `label` is simply a SVG `<text>` element, whose tweakable properties can be [found in this document](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Marks#text). And by modifying the **styling** of the axis label, you change the **styling** of **ALL** x-axis labels.

In the end, it means that by specifying `text = c("one","two","three")`, you end up with  manually **setting every x-axis tick label to an array** `["one", "two", "three"]`, which is joined to form the string `one,two,three`.

---

#### Solution

By default, `ggvis` will determine axis properties  for you, including

- How many ticks on the axis?
- What are the values of the ticks?

This is how, without specifying `add_axis("y", ...)`, you end up with a nicely render y-axis. 
But you can manually override the ticks by specifying the `values` property in `add_axis()` function.

For example,

```
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3) ) %>%
  ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_axis("x",
           value=c(1, 2, 3),
           properties=axis_props(
    labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10)))
```

This gives us:

[image]

Closer, but not there yet, because the labels are numbers, not the strings you want.

Finally, in order to change the labels, we can simply change the data on the X-axis from numerics to factors, like:

```
x <- factor(c(1,2,3), labels=c("one", "two", "three"))
data.frame(x = x, y = c(1,2,3) ) %>%
  ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_axis("x", values=x, 
           properties=axis_props(labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10)))
```

which will give you [image]

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try repeating `add_axis()` function for each label you wish for, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,3) ) %>%
  ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_axis("x",values = c(1,1), properties=axis_props(
           labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10, text = 'one', dx = 10))) %>%
  add_axis("x",values = c(2,2), properties=axis_props(
           labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10, text = 'two', dx 10))) %>%
  add_axis("x",values = c(3,3), properties=axis_props(
           labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10, text = 'three', dx = 10)))
```

I had data with too many categories so the factoring solution wouldn't work for me. Notice that I always called a vector with the same repeated number under **values** parameter. I don't know why but when I called single numbers render did not happened. Solution I found was to was to input the same number twice xD. Also **dx** argument can do good here, avoiding label-axis overlays:

[image: Code output]

If your variable has too many categories and you wish for only few labels this is a way to achieve custom labels.