# ggvis - custom non-numeric y-axis labels showing as 'NaN'

Tags: r, ggvis

**EDIT:** Sample code updated with more complex example

I have a data frame with (x, y) values and a name for each pair, and I'm plotting it in a ggvis scatterplot. SO users already pointed me to this post ([How do I label plot tick marks using ggvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235107/how-do-i-label-plot-tick-marks-using-ggvis)) and I updated my code to reflect what I saw there by using `factor()` to create the list of custom y-axis labels `ylabels_` which is fed to `values =` under the `add_axis()` statement. Here is the new code:

```
library(stringi)
require(ggvis)

set.seed(13)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:15, 
                 y = c(rep.int(1, 15), 
                       rep.int(4, 15), 
                       rep.int(7, 15)))

ylabels_ <- factor(c(1,4,7), labels = stri_rand_strings(3, 7))

df %>%
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% 
  add_axis("y", values = ylabels_)
```

My axis labels are still coming back with `NaN` instead of the factors. Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION EDIT:** Here is my code that I finally got to work. Note I changed the x values to be staggered so I could distinguish between the three lines.

```
library(stringi)
require(ggvis)

set.seed(13)
df <- data.frame(x = c(seq(1, length.out = 15, by = 3),
                       seq(2, length.out = 15, by = 3),
                       seq(3, length.out = 15, by = 3)),
                 y = factor(c(rep.int(1, 15), 
                       rep.int(4, 15), 
                       rep.int(7, 15)), labels = c("one", "four", "seven"),
                       ordered = T))

df %>%
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%
  scale_ordinal("y", domain = c("seven", "four", "one")
```

I don't understand why in the `domain =` portion I had to reverse the order of the factors for them to show in the correct order. If anyone has any insight on that, it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in the linked answer, the new factor variable is used as the `y` variable.  You can use it for your `values`, as well, but it's not necessarily needed.

Making the new factor based on `y` but using `name` as the labels is to get the `name` variable in the correct order for plotting.

```
df$ylabels_ <- factor(df$y, labels = stri_rand_strings(3, 7))
```

Because you are now working with a factor variable on the y axis, `layer_points` needs to be used explicitly.

```
df %>%
    ggvis(~x, ~ylabels_) %>% 
    layer_points()
```

Note that this whole approach will only work if the original `y` data are integers.

Comment: I think the example I gave is too simple - I'm going to post a revised example

Comment: @JonathanH If the issue is repeated y values, put the new variable in your dataset instead of making a stand-alone vector. But as per my note about continuous variables, the factor will lead to equal spacing instead of "continuous" spacing.

Comment: I ended up making many more modifications to the code, but your answer helped get me to where I needed to be!

Answer (score 0):

Call me a fool, but I'm calling this a bug (which, BTW, is not answering your question):

```
## set up data
lab <- factor(1:15, labels=stri_rand_strings(15, 7))
val <- 1:15

## all works according to expectations on the "x" axis
data.frame(xx=lab, yy=val) %>%
    ggvis(~xx, ~yy) %>% 
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("x", values=lab,
             properties=axis_props(labels=list(angle=90, fontSize = 10)))

## nothing works according to expectations on the "y" axis
## attempt 1
data.frame(xx=val, yy=lab) %>%
    ggvis(~xx, ~yy) %>% 
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("y", values=lab,
             properties=axis_props(labels=list(angle= 0, fontSize = 10)))

## attempt 2
data.frame(xx=val, yy=as.numeric(val)) %>%
    ggvis(~xx, ~yy) %>% 
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("y", values=lab,
             properties=axis_props(labels=list(angle= 0, fontSize = 10)))
```

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is as you described it, but the solution I found that worked for me is above